# DataGridView ArgumentOutOfRangeException C#

Tags: c#, datagridview

I'm working with a DataGridView but sometimes when I try to insert a value give me the error **ArgumentOutOfRangeException** .

For example:

```
getMaterialesInforme[2, 1].Value = Convert.ToInt32(sumaMP).ToString();
```

*(getMaterialesInforme is a DataGridView)*

This error is because cell [2, 1] doesn't exist so **is there a way to create this cell before insert the value? and even better, is there a way to create a DataGridView for example from the cell [0, 0] to cell [40, 10]**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @SteveZ sorry, DataGridView

Comment: You can create datagridview rows and columns manually but there is better way. I'd like to suggest you to prepare data for grid view using the list of objects and to use [DataGridView.DataSource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/how-to-bind-objects-to-windows-forms-datagridview-controls)  to show data list in the grid.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
for(int i = 0; i <= 40; i++)
{
    getMaterialesInforme.Columns.Add($"Col{i}", $"Col{i}");
}

for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++)
{
    getMaterialesInforme.Rows.Add();
}
```